# Vagrant installed through Chef (Kitchen) ignoring designated private IP in .kitchen.yml file

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I have the following information as part of my .kitchen.yml file where I am specifying the private_network ip.

```
    - name: dcos-bootstrap
driver:
  network:
    - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.3.37"}]
run_list: abc::_dcos_bootstrap
driver:
  customize:
    cpus: 1
    memory: 2048
attributes:
  abc:
    defg:
      enable: true
      kube_node: true
includes:
  - centos-7.3
```

But when I do "ip a" on my vagrant machine, I get the following result with ip as 10.0.2.15 and not 192.168.3.37 -

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:cb:e3:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
   valid_lft 86260sec preferred_lft 86260sec
inet6 fe80::df13:cd81:535b:3d27/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
link/ether 02:42:26:d3:6b:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Could somebody please help? I am using Vagrant 2.0.1.

Full kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  customize:
  cpus: 1
  memory: 2048

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  data_path: test/shared
  require_chef_omnibus: 12.17.44-1

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04
  - name: centos-7.3

suites:
  - name: dcos-bootstrap
    driver:
       network:
           - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.3.37"}]
   run_list: abc::_dcos_bootstrap
   driver:
   customize:
       cpus: 1
       memory: 2048
   attributes:
       abc:
           defg:
           enable: true
           kube_node: true
  includes:
       - centos-7.3
```

Comment: Please show the complete kitchen config.

Comment: @coderanger - I have included it below

Comment: In the future, you can edit your question to add more info, it is not actually an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have the `driver` key under the suite object. It needs to look like this instead:

```
   suites:
     - name: dcos-bootstrap
       run_list: abc::_dcos_bootstrap
       driver:
         customize:
           cpus: 1
           memory: 2048
         network:
           - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.3.37"}]
       attributes:
           abc:
               defg:
               enable: true
               kube_node: true
       includes:
           - centos-7.3
```

Otherwise the second instance of the `driver` key totally overwrites the first, as you noticed.

Comment: That was a silly mistake on my part. It worked. Thanks a ton!